# MYSQL / PHP - Efficient method for attaching users to a project

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, normalization, table-relationships

I'm building a system that has a user table and a project table. I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to connect users to a project.

I'm was thinking about a table that records the relationship, but I wasn't sure if a serialized list in one field would work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join table (e.g. `UserJoinProject`) would be my preference and would be well normalized. Assuming you have an ID column as a primary key for projects and for users.

Serializing the list will make it difficult for mysql to do any kind of operation on that data.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I just wondered about the size of a db that contains many relationships

Comment: Size shouldn't be an issue in terms of storage and you're unlikely to save much (if any) by keeping the relationship in one of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If it is many to many relationship then you can create another table which just associates project id with a user id.

Comment: Same as mopoke, didn't see his answer as we posted same time. :)